# How do I automate testing in Codename One on a headless server?

Tags: automated-tests, codenameone

I'm aware that JUnit doesn't work in Codename One projects which is becoming a real problem for us, but also it seems that the Codename One tests cannot be run on a headless server which means a separate automated testing path for these apps.

Is there a way to run the Codename One tests on a headless server?

Testing business logic in JUnit and then integrating it into the app isn't practical, running it on the devices themselves isn't important (just automating the testing on the simulator / JavaSE version is fine)

Answer (score 0):

We had discussed a mock version of Codename One for that purpose which should be relatively easy to implement. However, CI is an enterprise feature and none of our enterprise developers made that request.

Currently our bigger priority is device farm support for TDD.

Comment: It isn't really the Enterprise CI option that I'm looking for where the build server automatically returns the result. Its simply running the CN1 alternative to JUnit on a server without an IDE or GUI.

Comment: I understand that, what I'm explaining is the motivation behind our priorities. When we implement features like this we think first of the people who are in effect paying our salaries and keeping the rest of Codename One free. For them device farms are more important than mock tests. If you want to make a pull request with support for this it would be great and we would accept it

Comment: I didn't ask for mock tests though that would be useful too. I just want to be able to run the tests on the simulator on a headless server. Seems like its not possible.

Comment: The mock tests would be required as the regular testing framework uses the JavaSE port of Codename One so it might have issues in a headless server. Notice that if we support device testing we might be able to do mock tests for free as native OS's already have mock frameworks of their own.